# Docker Swarm Service-Task not running

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I guess I am just overlooking something particular but I just do not get it

I have a `docker swarm` "Cluster" on my local system. 
Now I create a service (e. g. mysql).

But now, even though there is the associated task, this task is not executed and I have no idea why...

I do not think that this is an error, I think I just forgot something.

Comment: What's the output of `docker service logs mysql` on your manager host? Could you share commands you'are using? Some more information is needed ;)

Comment: Ah - There is the error - Yesterday it seemed to be empty. Whatever - Thank you for your help :-)